# Test for Functoriality

Tags: category-theory

Being at the initial stages of studying Cat Theory, one of my first questions concerns whether there is a test for functoriality.  What I mean by this is whether, given two categories C and D, there a test to see if a functor can exist between them? If I understand correctly, this is not an issue for two small categories (bc a functor would always exist).

So, in the case of two given large categories, what can we say about whether a functor exists between them (without trying to specifically indentify such a functor)?

Comment: Is there a test for something being a group? Or a compact set? You check whether the conditions hold or not.

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction between small and large categories is germane here.  Perhaps it would improve your Question to outline what you have in mind for a functor between two (arbitrary) small categories.

Comment: You may know that every group is a category, and it is a worthwhile exercise to check that a (covariant) functor between two such categories is a homomorphism. So in particular this question subsumes the question "Is there a homomorphism between any two groups?" If you answer the small question, I think you will see the answer to the large one.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear why you think smallness of categories makes it easier to find functors between them.  If $C$ is any category and $D$ is any nonempty category, you can pick any object $X$ in $D$ and define a functor $C\to D$ which sends every object of $C$ to $X$ and every morphism of $C$ to $1_X$.  Smallness is irrelevant to this.

(On the other hand, if $D$ is empty, then there cannot exist any functor $C\to D$ unless $C$ is also empty, since there are no objects to send the objects of $C$ to.)

Comment: At the risk of changing my question too much, could you take a look at question 2355376, where I propose to find a functor between Sets and Sets, only to discover by example that there may be problems with that functor.  (And thus my quest for a test for functoriality, in general, and specific cases.)